# What will increase my Hunter Rank?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

My current understanding is that Hunter Rank increases based on story progression for a while, and then at a certain point, it "unlocks", and will increase based on any quests.

I've found a few sites that describe it at a high level, but I'd love to specifically know how it progresses even based on the earlier story quests; my regular co-op pals are a little ahead of me, and I can't tell how many quests/expeditions/etc. it will take to rank up so I can join them on quests. Being able to see how many quests between certain ranks would help me gauge how much I need to accomplish before catching up.

**EDIT**
@Vemonus's answer is helpful; however, I'm looking for what specific quests, expeditions, etc. **even within the main story** which will increase my rank. I understand that there is a cap of sorts, which keeps one from grinding and skipping through the story. I also understand that "Assigned" quests are the story quests, but I've found that **not every story mission seems to increase my rank.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the main story, your Hunter Rank is capped and only increases as you progress through the story. For the most part, each major quest (or group of quests) raises your Hunter Rank by 1, all the way through 15, once you defeat

> Xeno'Jiiva.

After that point, *all* of the extra HR experience you'd accrued but hadn't been counted towards your actual HR is applied. For instance, when mine became unlocked, I jumped from 15 to 26 immediately. Hunting large monsters will further raise your Hunter Rank, with more difficult hunts granting more experience (low rank gives almost nothing, whereas high rank gives a decent amount). Multiple monster hunts seem to grant a lot of experience, as well, scaled with the number of monsters you hunted. For example, I completed the five-monster Event quest earlier this week and went from about a quarter of the way from 40 to 41 all the way to 41.

The major exceptions I can recall to this 1:1 rule were when multiple story quests were assigned to you simultaneously and you could do them in whatever order you wanted. For instance, when you get three quests to slay Kushala Daora, Teostra, and Vaal Hazak, none of them raise your HR for completing them.

However, it's not very important to know which quests raise your HR, because the Assigned quests work differently than quests in previous Monster Hunter iterations. In previous games, you were given generic quests, but only a small subset were required to progress through the game and the game did not explicitly tell you what they were. In World, to uncap your HR and complete the story, you must complete **all** of the Assigned quests, without exception.

Additionally, there are two other caps on your Hunter Rank that are removed once you beat the corresponding Assigned quest. You will have one at 29, which requires you to beat 2 tempered Bazelguese, and one at 49, which requires you to beat a tempered Kirin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vemonus. I've seen much of this info on other sites, but didn't see the specific "each major quest" part. So you would say it's definitely quests I have to select from the board / handler, and I'll never receive HR from going on an expedition or being told to do some other scripted thing?

Comment: @zarose not until you complete the story. When you defeat the last monster for the story, the game literally tells you your hunter rank cap is removed and you instantly get boosted by however much HR you'd been building up in the background. After that point, there is a meter that appears at the end of hunts and it will show your HR progress.

Comment: hmmm, I'm interested in a more detailed answer then. I'd like to know which quests' completion will actually increase my rank, even within the story. I'll edit my question to help make that clearer.

Comment: @zarose I can't tell you that information accurately because I beat the story so long ago (my file is at 110 hours), but I'm not entirely sure how useful knowing which quest gets you to which rank is... just beat the story, and you'll be uncapped. Investigations, quests, and events all raise your HR, but none of it counts until the story is complete.

Comment: @zarose I don't understand why it would matter which specific quests would raise your HR. If your friends are further, you don't need to know which ones to pick, you just keep doing Assigned quests until you're at the same point. That is literally the only thing that determines your HR until you've completed the story.

Comment: Only assignments increase your hunter rank(until main story completion, then this answer is 100% correct). Just do those and your rank will increase. Mostly every 2-3 is an increase.

Comment: @Rapitor investigations do too? Unless you're grouping those with assignments

Comment: @Vemonus I'd like to know just so I can estimate a time frame (especially since most quests are timed) and give an expectation as to how long I might be if they're really itching to do a quest that requires a rank above me. They're not done with the story either, so they're not vastly ahead.

Comment: @zarose the solution there would be to ask them what their current story quest is... you could easily check how many you have to do to catch up. But if you want to just guess, assume two quests per HR so you don't underestimate the time it'll take and just multiply that by 50 minutes (or however many minutes you feel comfortable estimating a quest will take you on average)

Answer (score 0):

Every (yes, **every**) quest contributes to your hunter rank, but it is hidden until the ending, blocked by your nominate hunter rank locked by your story progress. [Kiranico](https://mhworld.kiranico.com/quests) notes that even ☆1 assigned quests will award you hunter rank points upon completion.

Also, certain event quests are capable of boosting your hunter rank more than average. They are usually noted in the event quest schedule as "a good quest for raising your hunter rank" (and master rank, for Iceborne Master Rank quests) and also have special remarks in the quest description. For example, No Tomorrow for Usurpers, in which you face a tempered Bazelgeuse, grants you almost half a hunter rank worth of experience point. Although not explicitly noted, arch-tempered monster quests also seem to grant equivalent experience points to such hunter rank boost quests, so if you are used to arch-tempered level threats, you may also try such quests.

Aside from that, hunting tempered monsters of high threat level seem to contribute to the hunter rank more.

Note that if the subject quest is Master Rank the mechanism also applies for your master rank. Useful information to know, since the end contents of Iceborne is unlocked at higher master ranks than in World's hunter ranks.

Comment: To note, non-master rank quests never boost the master rank. Those quests only ever boost the hunter rank. Whereas master rank quests boost the master rank as well as the hunter rank